# How to properly use CSS borders to visualize a value chain?

Tags: css, border, pseudo-element

I'm trying to create a CSS based value chain look-a-like:

[image: Value Chain]

After doing a little research I could find out, that I should use pseudo elements. So I managed to add them, but I can't make them overlap each other.

(Don't mind the colors, I'm using them for dev purposes.)

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #c3c3c3;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 13px 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.chain-link {
  position: relative;
}
.chain-link:after,
.chain-link:before {
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.chain-link:after {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-left-color: black;
  border-width: 20px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}
.chain-link:before {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-left-color: white;
  border-width: 20px;
  margin-left: -35px;
}
.chain-link:first-child:before {
  border-left-color: red;
}
.chain-link:last-child:after {
  border-left-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="chain-link">10</li>
  <li class="chain-link">20</li>
  <li class="chain-link">30</li>
  <li class="chain-link">40</li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone help? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/7t9ruxgr/

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #c3c3c3;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 13px 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.chain-link {
  position: relative;
}
.chain-link:after,
.chain-link:before {
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.chain-link:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #c3c3c3;
  margin-left: 35px;
  border-width: 20px 16px 21px 20px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.chain-link:before {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-left-color: white;
  border-width: 20px;
  margin-left: -35px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="chain-link">10</li>
  <li class="chain-link">20</li>
  <li class="chain-link">30</li>
  <li class="chain-link">40</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's it. What did you modify? Edit: Uh, I see: The `z-index` did the job :-)